# Cannot change spark.driver.memory even though is set in spark-defaults

Tags: apache-spark, configuration, pyspark, cluster-computing

I am using an Amazon EMR cluster and I want to change the driver heap memory.
I gave the following configuration to the cluster:

```
[{"classification":"spark-defaults",  
"properties":  
{"spark.executor.memory":"36g",   
 "spark.driver.memory":"36g",   
 "spark.driver.cores":"3", 
 "spark.default.parallelism":"174",  
 "spark.executor.cores":"3", 
 "spark.executor.instances":"29", 
 "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead":"4g",   
 "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled":"false"}}]
```

However when I check the environment tab in spark UI, the driver memory still remains fixed to 1000m while the rest is correctly set.  What am I doing wrong?
I am using a 10 r4.4xlarge machines cluster.
Thank you.

Comment: Properties set through SparkConf programmatically have higher precedence, the flags from command line, then spark-defaults.conf. So, You need to check the previous too or at least provide them in your question

Comment: I didn't set any props programmatically and left the default amazon command line props

Comment: Do you have access to the ```spark-submit``` cmd to check if there is a ```--driver-memory``` flags ? Anyway 36G for a driver memory is not a good idea. If you need that much memory, you may have a design problem...

Comment: I read [this](https://aws.amazon.com/it/blogs/big-data/best-practices-for-successfully-managing-memory-for-apache-spark-applications-on-amazon-emr/) article rom an AWS engineer and according to the dimension of data I am going to process it comes out this config. What is your recommended dim?

Comment: Spark driver build the DAG and and distribute the tasks composing the stages composing the jobs. It should require small memory footprint ! 
If you need more, you may call something like ```.collect``` which fetch data from every executors...and this must avoided !